# show random php page in iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to load .php in iframe. I have (more than) 10 php files in a folder with index.html,which has the iframe. In this i frame I would like load the .php files randomly (withou repeat-If all 10 files shown then show the messgae "No More") when user click Next... How do I write this javascript.

My index.html looks like this . This file and all the .php files placed in the same folder.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.cs" />
   </head>
   <body class="is-demo">
   <header id="demo-header">
         <div class="details">
            <div class="inner">
               <h1>one.php title</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
         <ul class="actions">
            <li><a href="index.php" ><span>Home Page</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ten.php" class="button square previous"><span>Previous</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="javascript:choose_random_page()" class="button square next"><span>Next</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </header>


      <script>
      var iframe = document.getElementById("demo-iframe");
var pages = ["one.htm", "two.htm", "three.htm", 
             "four.htm", "five.htm", "six.htm", 
             "seven.htm", "eight.htm","nine.htm",
             "ten.htm"];

function choose_random_page() {
   if(pages.length>0) {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random(pages.length));

      var ranom_page = pages.slice(r,1);
      iframe.src = random_page;

   } else {
      alert("No more pages to load");
   }
}
      </script>

      <div id="demo-main">
         <iframe id="demo-iframe" src="" data-responsive="1">-</iframe>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your pages to array, mix it, change the iframe src with javascript, exclude page from array after that.

```
var locations = ['a.php', 'b.php', 'c.php'];

for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    // I put code for changing locations inside setTimeout, but you can change it with your logic.

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('demo-iframe').src = locations[i];
    }, i * 1000)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to acheive that is to have all possible pages in an array, in any order.

Then once the function triggered to choose the random page, it should do the following:

a- check if pages array still has pages to choose from

b- select a random index between 0 and the number of elements in the array

c- slice the element from that array out and load iframe source with the value

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("demo-iframe");
var pages = ["one.php", "two.php", "three.php", 
             "four.php", "five.php", "six.php", 
             "seven.php", "eight.php","nine.php",
             "ten.php"];

function choose_random_page() {
   if(pages.length>0) {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random(pages.length));
      
      var ranom_page = pages.slice(r,1);
      iframe.src = random_page;
      
   } else {
      alert("No more pages to load");
   }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="demo-iframe">
```

Comment: I think https://templated.co/projection this website using as what am I expect. How do code this..?